# MySQL to Percona page load time increase?

Tags: mysql, percona

```
Page Time: 0.0915s

Memory: 5.0191 MB (Peak: 5.4852 MB)

Queries (10, time: 0.0037s, 4.1%)
```

After doing a change from MySQL to Percona my Page Time actually increased. Is that just because it lessens somewhere and tightens elsewhere? I don't mind, but I'd like to understand the reason.

This is seen using a debug from a XenForo installation with 15 - 30 users 24/7. Unfortunately I didn't check the queries time before so I'm not sure on that one if it increased or not, but I'll probably be staying on percona for a while.

Comment: As Bill has pointed out in his answer, there is little to go on here; if you could please provide some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to make any diagnosis, since you haven't isolated the performance of the queries versus the rest of your application.  I'd recommend to use New Relic to get some metrics about where your application is spending the majority of its time.

Another thing I'd guess is that your MySQL buffers were cleared as you must have shut it down to install Percona Server.  After the buffers have been made cold following a restart, it's natural for database queries to take longer for a little while.  In other words, the same slowdown might have happened if you had simply rebooted.

As query traffic loads pages of data and indexes into the buffers, the queries should return to the speed you're accustomed to.  How long this takes to "warm up" the buffers is variable; it depends on the rate of traffic to your site.

Here's an interesting article with tips on managing your MySQL cache buffers effectively:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/09/23/more-on-dangers-of-the-caches/